# AVAssetReferenceRestrictions on iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, avassetexportsession

> Workspace: iOS 13.0, Xcode 11.0

*TL;DR: Is there something wrong with AVAssetReferenceRestrictions in iOS 13?*

**Part 1:**

In `AVAsset.h`, the `AVAssetReferenceRestrictions` are defined as:

```
  @enum         AVAssetReferenceRestrictions
  @abstract     These constants can be passed in to AVURLAssetReferenceRestrictionsKey to control the resolution of references to external media data.

  @constant     AVAssetReferenceRestrictionForbidNone
    Indicates that all types of references should be followed.
  @constant     AVAssetReferenceRestrictionForbidRemoteReferenceToLocal
    Indicates that references from a remote asset (e.g. referenced via http URL) to local media data (e.g. stored in a local file) should not be followed.
  @constant     AVAssetReferenceRestrictionForbidLocalReferenceToRemote
    Indicates that references from a local asset to remote media data should not be followed.
  @constant     AVAssetReferenceRestrictionForbidCrossSiteReference
    Indicates that references from a remote asset to remote media data stored at a different site should not be followed.
  @constant     AVAssetReferenceRestrictionForbidLocalReferenceToLocal
    Indicates that references from a local asset to local media data stored outside the asset's container file should not be followed.
  @constant     AVAssetReferenceRestrictionForbidAll
    Indicates that only references to media data stored within the asset's container file should be allowed.
*/
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, AVAssetReferenceRestrictions) {
    AVAssetReferenceRestrictionForbidNone = 0UL,
    AVAssetReferenceRestrictionForbidRemoteReferenceToLocal = (1UL << 0),
    AVAssetReferenceRestrictionForbidLocalReferenceToRemote = (1UL << 1),
    AVAssetReferenceRestrictionForbidCrossSiteReference = (1UL << 2),
    AVAssetReferenceRestrictionForbidLocalReferenceToLocal = (1UL << 3),
    AVAssetReferenceRestrictionForbidAll = 0xFFFFUL,

    AVAssetReferenceRestrictionDefaultPolicy = AVAssetReferenceRestrictionForbidLocalReferenceToRemote
};
```

And an `AVAsset`'s property is defined as:

```
@property       referenceRestrictions
@abstract       Indicates the reference restrictions being used by the receiver.
@discussion
    For AVURLAsset, this property reflects the value passed in for AVURLAssetReferenceRestrictionsKey, if any. See AVURLAssetReferenceRestrictionsKey below for a full discussion of reference restrictions. The default value for this property is AVAssetReferenceRestrictionForbidNone.
@property (nonatomic, readonly) AVAssetReferenceRestrictions referenceRestrictions API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.7), ios(5.0), tvos(9.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(watchos);
```

So, although the documentation on the property explicitly says that the default value is `AVAssetReferenceRestrictionForbidNone`, `AVAssetReferenceRestrictionDefaultPolicy` is currently `AVAssetReferenceRestrictionForbidLocalReferenceToRemote`. Is the documentation not updated properly, or is `AVAssetReferenceRestrictionDefaultPolicy` something different than I expect?

**Part 2:**

In Swift counterpart, it's defined (converted?) as such:

```
  @enum         AVAssetReferenceRestrictions
  @abstract     These constants can be passed in to AVURLAssetReferenceRestrictionsKey to control the resolution of references to external media data.

  @constant     AVAssetReferenceRestrictionForbidNone
    Indicates that all types of references should be followed.
  @constant     AVAssetReferenceRestrictionForbidRemoteReferenceToLocal
    Indicates that references from a remote asset (e.g. referenced via http URL) to local media data (e.g. stored in a local file) should not be followed.
  @constant     AVAssetReferenceRestrictionForbidLocalReferenceToRemote
    Indicates that references from a local asset to remote media data should not be followed.
  @constant     AVAssetReferenceRestrictionForbidCrossSiteReference
    Indicates that references from a remote asset to remote media data stored at a different site should not be followed.
  @constant     AVAssetReferenceRestrictionForbidLocalReferenceToLocal
    Indicates that references from a local asset to local media data stored outside the asset's container file should not be followed.
  @constant     AVAssetReferenceRestrictionForbidAll
    Indicates that only references to media data stored within the asset's container file should be allowed.

public struct AVAssetReferenceRestrictions : OptionSet {

    public init(rawValue: UInt)

    public static var forbidRemoteReferenceToLocal: AVAssetReferenceRestrictions { get }

    public static var forbidLocalReferenceToRemote: AVAssetReferenceRestrictions { get }

    public static var forbidCrossSiteReference: AVAssetReferenceRestrictions { get }

    public static var forbidLocalReferenceToLocal: AVAssetReferenceRestrictions { get }

    public static var forbidAll: AVAssetReferenceRestrictions { get }

    public static var defaultPolicy: AVAssetReferenceRestrictions { get }
}
```

There is no option as `AVAssetReferenceRestrictionForbidNone` here. But the documentation explicitly says that there is so. So, who's in fault here, or is it a misunderstanding from my side?

**Part 3: How did I end here?**

> I've had to examine these
>   because we were able to select a video from `UIImagePickerController`,
>   then export it in `AVURLAsset` form to use in
>   `AVAssetExportSession`.
>   Everything was fine, it was working seamlessly until iOS 13.0. The feature works in the devices with iOS 12.4.1 and below.
>
> The usage of AVAssetReferenceRestrictions is in the initializer of the
>   `AVURLAsset`, and I believe that the default value has changed and it
>   doesn't let us export anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not your fault.

Until 2019-06-19, in the [Apple referenceRestrictions documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20190619134913/https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasset/1390489-referencerestrictions), the default value was `forbidNone`:

> The default value for this property is 
>   **forbidNone**
>   . See 
>   AVURLAssetReferenceRestrictionsKey
>    for a full discussion of reference restrictions.

Later, this page was changed to [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasset/1390489-referencerestrictions):

> The default value for this property is **defaultPolicy**. See AVURLAssetReferenceRestrictionsKey for a full discussion of reference restrictions.

The defaultPolicy now is `forbidLocalReferenceToRemote`, available only in iOS 13.

However, we have this paragraph:

> For AVURLAsset, this property reflects the value passed in for AVURLAssetReferenceRestrictionsKey, **if any**.

So, apparently, not passing a restrictionKey should work the same as `forbidNone`.

Have you tried this?

```
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: nil)
```

Comment: Passing `nil` works, thanks. I didn't expect this kind of a breaking change, but well...