# Trying to cast a local video file using AirPlay returns 'externalPlaybackNotSupportedForAsset' (-11870)

Tags: ios, swift, video, airplay, avasset

I'm currently having some troubles using *AVPlayer* and *AVAsset* in order to cast a video to an external screen using AirPlay.

After adding the *AVRoutePickerView* in order to have the AirPlay button, I was able to successfully cast videos to use AirPlay, creating an *AVAsset* from a remote URL.

If I try the same thing with a video file that was previously downloaded from the app (and it is still inside the internal app storage), *AVPlayer* fails and gives me an error code (-11870). The local video still plays correctly without AirPlay enabled.

After a couple of searches, I was able to find that the error code refers to [externalPlaybackNotSupportedForAsset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/averror/2967117-externalplaybacknotsupportedfora), though there is no further explanation on this or any mention of this error.

I stumbled upon [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58136254/avassetreferencerestrictions-on-ios-13) regarding *AVAssetReferenceRestrictions* and thought it could help me fix the issue, but even after changing the restriction parameter or setting the options: argument to **nil** when initializing the *AVAsset* object didn't work.

Worth to note the fact that also casting using Google Cast does not work for local files, whereas remote video files are casting correctly.

Does anyone know how to deal with this issue?

I'm using XCode 11 and an iPhone 6S with iOS 13.5.1.

Kind Regards

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue with Xcode 12.4, iOS 14.4 as well.
I'm only playing audio without the video.
Also, the playback is fine with Apple TV; but it does not work with Airplay 2 supported third-party TVs.

Comment: Did you guys found a solution for it? Same here using the latest version of the Xcode, the stream video can play fine on Apple TV but it returns that same error when I try to play using AirPlay on Roku TV

Answer (score -4):

For those of you who are only looking to play the local audio file (i.e. music), be sure to set AVPlayer's `allowsExternalPlayback` to `false`. By setting this flag, AirPlay can properly play local file.